# How to create a new page on form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm attempting to create a new page every time a form is submitted. It'll be an order status page- one that'll be updated periodically. Basically, I want the user to see a form confirmation page, and I want it to be permanent link (that they can visit later).

My first thought was using variables in the URL, like so:

```
http://www.example.org/member.php?id=123
```

And then calling the id using `GET`

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

`http://www.example.org/member.php` would be a template, just waiting for the few details which are specific to the user. 
Once I have this in place, I could use a simple `if` statement to check their order status.

For example,

```
if ($id === "user_id") {
   echo "Your order is: Pending";
}
```

However, this seems like a bad idea, just for the security aspect of it. If someone else guesses a user ID, they can view their order status. Going off of that, here's my first question.

**If the user ID is long enough, is this a secure practice?**

Otherwise, what are some other methods of doing this? Creating a new page every time the form is submitted feels like a bad practice- people could spam it, and there's a possibility that someone could exploit this to create malicious pages on the site.

Any suggestions? Most major retail sites have order confirmation pages (think ebay.com)- how do they do it? Also, is my suggested URL format secure?

Comment: Eh... a login, with a template as you suggested? If the user is logged in, and the ID in the URL is an order connected to the user, show it. If not, just redirect or show an error message. Doing this without a login IS bad practice, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most ideal scenario is you force users to login prior to submitting the form then provide them with a list of their past orders of which they can check the status providing the user_id of the order matches the id from the session of the logged in user. Give each order in the list a link like yoursite.com/orders/1 then query for an order with an id of one with a user_id matching the logged in users id to ensure they're the only ones that can view it.

If you don't want to have to do any of that and just provide a permanent link to the status page I'd save a long randomly generated string against the order and provide it to the user to check in the future, e.g

**yoursite.com/orders/wUk1DhfxMh** if you're using a framework with some routing
 or **yoursite.com/orders.php?code=wUk1DhfxMh** if you're not.

Query the database to select the order with the matching code, ensure you prevent MySQL injection and sanitize the $_GET input.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to make a new page?
You could just have a basic "confirm" page (ex. http://yoursite.com/order/confirm) which *uses PHP sessions* to create a customized confirm page–
Other than that, IF you make a new page, you should use ID's in the URL and ALSO check the session id. (ex. http://yoursite.com/order/confirm/ABsisnEALnsoSK?yyyy=xxxx) and then ALSO check if the user is logged in.

Lastly, [cymath](http://cymath.com) has a good example of async page-creation; although it isn't exactly what you are looking for.
EDIT: It is not page creation, it's like what I said before: one page with extra parameters in the url: a permanent link, just using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you are having some doubts about how to make the algorithm of your app, here's what i thought to this case:

1. `Insert` the order at your database, get the id of the insertion and give it to the user.
2. Set the page where the user will check the status to receive a `$_GET['id']`, check (`SELECT`) if this id exists in the database.
3. (if the user exists): get the information you need from the table
   you store them. (`FETCH_ASSOC` or `FETCH_OBJECT`)
4. (if the user don't exist):show an error.

*If you are experiencing some doubts about how to code CodeSchool is offering free trial on all courses this weekend.*

**If the user ID is long enough, is this a secure practice?**

**R:** To improve the security of the transactions, try to understand/learn about PDO Class, i think it will get your code to next level if you aggregate some Good Practices and Design Patterns.

For more information, visit [PHP's Documentation](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php).